Decode this phrase please: 8447 789953 927 765833
I have encoded a phrase for you to be decoded:
8447 789953 927 765833

What's hidden in this message?

https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do


Using dCode's T9 converter, this message reads:
8447 789953 927 765833
THIS PUZZLE WAS SOLVED

